# Reactive streams map operator never getting executed

Tags: groovy, project-reactor

For the below code

```
Mono<String> input = 
        Mono.just("input")
                .map {
                   println "inside map"
                   it + "added"
                 }
                 .transform {
                  Mono.just("hello")
                }

input.subscribe {println it}
```

The console looks like as below.

```
16:11:49.056 [main] DEBUG reactor.util.Loggers$LoggerFactory - Using Slf4j logging framework
hello
```

The code inside the `map` function was never executed. I understand that `transform` method executes at [assembly time](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/index.html#advanced-mutualizing-operator-usage) rather than the subscription.

- Why did Reactor just decide to not process my upstream `map` operator. Did it intelligently decide that since I am not in anyway referring to the output of the `map` operator that it need not execute `map` at all ?
- Is this behaviour configurable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `transform` does not automatically subscribe to your original `Mono`. It's your responsibility to chain your logic onto it. Since nothing subscribes to it, it will never get triggered.

As the example you sent is dummy, it's difficult to say what would be the right thing to do. It depends on your use case.

A few thing you can do, though:

1. Get rid of transform and just simply use `then` operator:

```
Mono<String> input = 
        Mono.just("input")
                .map {
                   println "inside map"
                   it + "added"
                 }
                 .then(Mono.just("hello"))
```

2. If for some reason you need `transform`, then chain your logic onto your original Mono:

```
Mono<String> input = 
        Mono.just("input")
                .map {
                   println "inside map"
                   it + "added"
                 }
                 .transform {
                   it.then(Mono.just("hello"))
                }
```